# Laravel upgrade to version 8 throws error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I have just upgraded to version 8 and get this error in logs when I start the artisan serv service. Do you have any advice on what to do?

I submit the error that is thrown:

```
    local.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::encrypt() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\vipa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php on line 67 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies::encrypt() must be an instance of Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response, null given, called in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php on line 67 at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php:138)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->encrypt(NULL)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vipa\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
#26 {main}
"}
```

17/11/2021

I managed to solve it by modifying the Handler class in this way:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

and adding on the Routeserviceprovider the constant Home:

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

Thanks anyway for the support

Comment: This is most likely an issue with other middleware in the chain. Which version of Laravel did you upgrade from?

Comment: From 5.8 to 8.0

Comment: The error usally indicates that one of your middleware (or the route handler) returned null instead of a response instance. You need to go through each middleware that is in the chain to determine which it is.

Comment: Ok, what do you advise me to check?
I'm not very expert on laravel.